# TikZ: How to distinguish multiple vertices with the same id?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

(Almost minimal) working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

  \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
  \pgfsetlayers{background,main} 

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Parallel Boruvka's}
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{selected vertex} = [vertex, fill=red!24]
    \tikzstyle{root} = [vertex, fill=blue!24]
    \tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
    \tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\small]
    \tikzstyle{selected edge} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,red!50]
    \tikzstyle{dfs} = [draw,line width=5pt,-,blue!20]

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, auto,swap]
        \foreach \pos/\name/\fr in {{(0,1)/1/1},{(0,1)/2/3}, {(1,1)/2/1}, {(2,1)/3/1},  {(2,1)/2/3}}
            \node<\fr->[vertex] (\name) at \pos {$\name$};
        \foreach \source/ \dest /\weight in {1/2/3,2/3/1}
            \path[edge] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{figure}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output on second and third slide:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is that all vertices have the same id as on slide 3 but the edge weights stay the same as they are on the second slide. Can this be done?

A (silly) side question: Where can I find documentation that would help me in this case?/ All I can find are examples somehow but no real explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the name `2` to different nodes on different slides. To avoid this, label the nodes uniquely, even if the node content is the same:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Parallel Boruvka's}
    \tikzset{
      vertex/.style = {circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt},
      edge/.style = {draw,thick,-},
      weight/.style = {font=\small},
    }
    \begin{figure}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8, auto,swap]
          \foreach \pos/\name/\fr/\label in {{(0,1)/1/1/1},{(0,1)/2/3/2a}, {(1,1)/2/1/2}, {(2,1)/3/1/3},  {(2,1)/2/3/2b}}
              \node<\fr->[vertex] (\label) at \pos {$\name$};
          \foreach \source/ \dest /\weight in {1/2/3,2/3/1}
              \path[edge] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: unique names]

Note that you should use `\tikzset` and not `\tikzstyle` as the latter is deprecated.